# Why does Mongoose can't find an user on a query if it exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been working on a Nodejs+Express+Mongoose API that handles user registration/login, everything works perfectly when a user signs up, but when the user wants to login it says it can't find the user. Let me show you the code:

```
    module.exports.registerUser = (req, res) => {
    var user = new User();

    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.name = req.body.name;

    user.setPassword(req.body.password);

    user.save((err) => {
        var token;
        token = user.generateJwt();
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            'token': token,
            'user': user,
        });
    });
};
```

When I register (I'm testing this with Postman) I get this message, showing everything it's OK:

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0ODg1MDcwNjUsImlhdCI6MTQ4ODQyMDY2NX0.GD0NehQ1EYEnOKx2OJWALpkHB8u5N_9Zjm1dcuEdl7I",
  "user": {
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "Stack Overflow",
    "email": "stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com",
    "_id": "58b77f39cf5e8d5f3ffdb4ff"
  }
}
```

The password gets hashed, that's why the JSON doesn't contain it.

And this is the code for user login:

```
module.exports.loginUser = (req, res) => {
    var password = req.body.password;
    var email = req.body.email;
    User.findOne({'email': email}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                res.status(401).send({
                    message: 'Wrong password.'
                });
            } else {
                token = user.generateJwt();
                res.status(200);
                res.json({
                    'token': token,
                    'user': user
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: 'No user was found.'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But every time I hit the login button on postman with the same password and email, I get this:

```
{
  "message": "No user was found."
}
```

And this is the user schema:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = require('../config/secret');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    schoolID: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false
    },
    university: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    area: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Area'
    },
    project: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = (password) => {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) => {
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = () => {
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 1);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        email: this.email,
        name: this.name,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
    }, secret.secret);
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I can't find the solution to this problem, because the way I see it, everything should be working just nice. Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Update:
This is for checking the email is being sent correctly:

```
{
  "message": "No user was found. User: stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com password: stackoverflow"
}
```

Comment: can you confirm (developer tools network tab) that the `email` is being sent correctly

Comment: Are you getting any `err`? you are not returning from err `if` block, and your `!user` block seems to be always executed

Comment: @sidgate Let me check that and I'll notify you

Comment: @sidgate I got the same message. And I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Do you see the user in database? Any `err` on save? Update the callback in save to get saved `user` as second parameter. check if it is available

Comment: @sidgate No, I just checked and I don't see the user in the db :(, the error prints to `null`. And, I updated the callback and the savedUser does not print, so...